# C- Reaping Child Process and Background

Tags: c, shell

```
    pid_t pid;

    if ((pid == fork()) == 0){
            if (execvp(arg[0], arg) < 0) {
                printf("%s: Command not found.\n", arg[0]);
                exit(0);
            }

    }

    if (background == 0 )
    {
        int status;
        if (waitpid(pid, &status, 0) < 0)
            printf("waitfg: waitpid error");
        while(waitpid(-1, 0, WNOHANG) >= 0){}


    }
    else
    {
    printf("%d %s", pid, cmdline);
    }
```

I have this code for my program and I am trying to have the parent reap all child processes and the problem is that it is still not reaping. I am trying to use the code:

```
 while(waitpid(-1, 0, WNOHANG) >= 0){}
```

in order to reap but it seems to not get rid of the zombie process. What am I supposed to do to reap instead then

Also I am not sure if I am doing background right here.

Comment: Change `if ((pid == fork()) == 0){` by `if ((pid = fork()) == 0){`

Comment: Another one bites the dust, ('clever' compound expression).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code  is wrong:

```
pid_t pid;

if ((pid == fork()) == 0){  // PROBLEM HERE
        if (execvp(arg[0], arg) < 0) {
            printf("%s: Command not found.\n", arg[0]);
            exit(0);
        }

}
```

you compare `pid` which isn't initialized with result of `fork()` => Undefined behavior (and after, you compare the result of this comparison with 0)

You should replace `if ((pid == fork()) == 0){` by `if ((pid = fork()) == 0){`